# Windows Phone 8: Collision in rectangles

Tags: c#, windows, xna

So im working on a windows phone app and i need a way to detect weather the user has dragged a rectangle into another. ive got al of the dragging and everything sorted but i cannot for the life of me figure out how to detct a collision, i looked a little into xna and managed to bodge the bellow together if anybody could help out it would be much appriciated.

```
 double BoxLeft = characterMain.Margin.Left;
        double BoxTop = characterMain.Margin.Top;
        Rect r1 = new Rect(BoxLeft, BoxTop, 20, 20);
        txtblck2.Text = r1.X.ToString() + r1.Y.ToString();

        double badBoxLeft = BadGuy.Margin.Left;
        double badBoxTop = BadGuy.Margin.Top;
        Rect r2 = new Rect(badBoxLeft, badBoxTop,12, 100);
        txtblck3.Text = r2.X.ToString() + r2.Y.ToString();

        r1.Intersect(r2);


        if (r1.IsEmpty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Did it");
        }
```

Comment: `if(r1.Intersects(r2)) { /* there is an intersection */ }`

Answer (score 0):

Collision with rectangles is pretty easy, I don't know if u have searched anything but this will help you out a little:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersects.aspx

Also some tutorials you'll probably want to read:

http://jamessadlier.wordpress.com/tutorials/xna-4-0-collision-detection/
http://codeforcake.com/blog/?p=160

The basic collision works like this:
It basically does what it says.

```
if(r1.Intersects(r2)) 
{ 
    //Collision happend
    //Do something
}
```

Next time when you have a question be sure to check the internet real good, there are a lot of tutorials and good examples out there.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: I tired this but im getting this error Error 4 'System.Windows.Rect' does not contain a definition for 'Intersects' and no extension method 'Intersects' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Rect' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ive got that and im not getting any error but for some reason its not reconising the collision

Comment: Did you fix the problem?

Comment: yehh, it wasnt actually a problem the code was working fine, it was an issue with the device i was testing on wasnt showing messageboxes so i had to restart and worked fine!